# java.lang.NullPointerException error when trying to find record with a iterator

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, iterator

My iterator method is having trouble finding an entered record. The method I am using is this:

```
iterator = gamesList.listIterator();
int Code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Code:"));

boolean Found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < gamesList.size(); i++) 
{
    setMembers(iterator.next());
    if(obj.getId() == Code)
    {
        Found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(Found == true)
{
    System.out.println("Success!");
}
```

This method is proven to work with other programs of this type.

Comment: What line is causing the null pointer exception?

Comment: My guess is that you get a NPE because `getId()` returns a null `Integer`

Comment: What is `obj`, did you checked if it's `null`

Comment: It think the NullPointerException comes from your obj variable. Where do you initialize it?

Comment: Obj is my variable for instantiating a java class

Comment: The error is at the if() statement